# In WooCommerce, how to add a variation-specific (not product-specific) downloadable (PDF) file to a product page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I am making a WooCommerce store to sell physical products. Each product has multiple variations (Size, Color, etc.). I want to add a downloadable PDF file that would be specific to each variable (ProductA Size-M Color-Blue should have a downloadable PDF file, and ProductA Size-M Color-Red should have a ***different*** downloadable PDF file).

I cannot use images as the file need to be modified and sent back to me easily after the purchase is completed.

I have seen many "solutions" online recommending using extensions, but the ones I've tried only allow to add downloadable files that would be product-specific and not variation-specific as I need.

Thanks!